# Parse-load huge XML using Spring Batch framework

Tags: spring, spring-batch

I want to parse huge file with XML data and insert records into SQL server 2008. Database connection/Data insertion is managed by product framework.
I read XML data, validate it, create object and pass it to framework for insertion.

I am planning to divide XML file into small files, parse it using parser threads and run parallel load using different threads.

I am new to Spring framework. How can I do this using Spring Batch framework?
Do I need to divide file in Spring Batch? Will I be able to load data parallely?

Comment: You can user ExecuterFramwork to split huge xml and pass it to threads. For parsing XML use SAX parser.

Comment: you can use [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25021689/spring-batch-reading-a-large-flat-file-choices-to-scale-horizontally) as skeleton