# Performance issue with MultiResourcePartitioner in Spring Batch

Tags: memory-management, spring-batch, file-processing

I have a spring batch project that reads a huge zip file containing more than 100.000 xml files.

I am using MultiResourcePartitioner, and I have a Memory issue and my batch fails with

```
java.lang.OutOfMemoryError: GC overhead limit exceeded.
```

It seems like if all the xml files are loaded in memory and not garbaged after processing.

Is there a performant way to do this ?

Thanks.

Comment: What memory settings are you currently using?

Comment: I am getting this error when using these settings : -Xms512m -Xmx1024m. When I set -Xms1024m -Xmx4096m I don't get the error but the Heap is using 2Gb, it seems to be too much for 200.000 xml files of 4Ko each.

Comment: With 200,000 files, do you really need/want one partition per file?  You may want to consider writing your own `Partitioner` that groups files together into chunks.

Comment: I process each file individually, each xml is marshalled, then processed, then written to an XML file. Can you explain further what you mean by partioner that groups files into chunks ?

Comment: The `MultiResourcePartitioner` creates one partition (and therefore one `ExecutionContext` and one `StepExecution` per file.  With 200,000 files, you may wan to group them together so that you have less partitions.