# Multi threading in Spring Batch FlatFileItemReader and FlatFileItemWriter

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch

My requirement is to read and write a text file with more than 50k lines so I want to implement it in spring batch,

1. I want it to multi threaded and each thread should handle 1k lines and write it to output file using `FlatFileItemWriter`
2. and also I want to read input and output file names from job parameters to configuration

So please help me on this

Comment: Can you share the code you've written so far?

Comment: You can try Partitioner to handle your case.

Comment: FlatFileItemWriter is not thread safe (as written is javadoc)

Comment: For the first part you'll need to split the file up into multiple files, then finally read them using the MultiResourcePartitioner see http://stackoverflow.com/a/25022841